# Issue with importing framework in Swift with Cocoapods

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, cocoapods

I am new to Swift, but I learned the basics. I wanted to import a framework but I ran into issues. I will now explain what steps I followed and what failed.

1. I installed cocoapods by using terminal command: sudo gem install cocoapods
2. I then navigated to my projects root directory with terminal then used command: pod init
3. It created a podfile, and I edited it as I have shown below.

   platform :ios, '8.0'
   use_frameworks!

   target 'Testy' do

   end

   target 'TestyTests' do

   pod 'Kingfisher', '~> 1.8.1'

   end

   target 'TestyUITests' do

   pod 'Kingfisher', '~> 1.8.1'

   end
4. I then closed xcode and started the project by clicking 'Testy.xcworkspace' file.
5. At this point, I did not add any code, just built the project without issues, problems start here.
6. When i try to import my framework and build, it gives the follow error:

   Cannot load underlying module for 'Kingfisher'
7. So what might be the problem here? If you need additional info, ask me and I can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Podfile, you do not have "pod 'Kingfisher', '~> 1.8.1'" listed for the target "Testy".